# How to write a simple array in json?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array

var `array_list=["apple","orange","cat","dog"];`

How do i write this in json?

I saw tutorials in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)
 but it showed that json has name value/pairs,should we always write it in `name/value pairs` or is there a simpler format?.

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.

Comment: Key/value pairs are for objects, not arrays. w3schools is generally a bad reference, their answers are often incomplete, and sometimes wrong.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(array_list)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the **array** into json by `JSON.stringify`

```
var array_list=['apple','orange','cat','dog'];
var json_string = JSON.stringify(array_list);
```

And using `JSON.parse` you can parse the **JSON**

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json_string);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H2yN6/127/)**

Answer (score 4):

The JSON for that array is:

```
["apple","orange","cat","dog"]
```

JSON for arrays is the same as Javascript array literals, except that JSON doesn't allow missing elements or an optional trailing comma. And the elements of the array have to be valid JSON, so you have to use double quotes around strings, you can't use single quotes like Javascript allows.

You generally shouldn't have to worry about how to format JSON yourself, most languages have library functions that do it for you. In JS you use `JSON.stringify`, in PHP you use `json_encode()`.

Comment: thank you for the answer :-) am not trying to format it , i am just learning how to write json structure. Your answer helped me through :-)

Answer (score 1):

You use name/value pairs for dictionaries. You use a sequence of values for arrays.

```
{ "name1": 1, "name2": "text" }
[ 1, 2, 3, "apple", "orange", 3.2 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

An array is a perfectly legal JSON serializable object.

```
var array_list=["apple","orange","cat","dog"];
var json_string = JSON.stringify(array_list);
```